# Progress Bar Per Object and Status

Tags: apex, visualforce, graph

Wondering if you can guide me a way to show a progress bar on my VF Page or a separate VF page.  What's the best way to approach it and possibly a simple startup code for me to work on?

Scenario:

I have 4 objects with statuses on each object.  If the record has moved to the next object I would like a progress bar and status info to show on top of the progress bar.  Primarily, I would like to have a progress bar first then add the status.

An example of the progress bar:

[image: Progress Bar]

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on this requirement few days back, although the Ui was a little different. Hope this will help you.

Have the following CSS to style your status nodes.

```
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #progress {
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 12px;
        clear: both;
        line-height: 1em;
        margin: 0 -1px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #progress li {
        float: left;
        padding: 10px 30px 10px 40px;
        background: #E6E6E6;
        color: #fff;
        position: relative;
        border-top: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
        width: 18%;
        margin: 0 1px;
    }

    #progress li:before {
        content: '';
        border-left: 16px solid #E6E6E6;
        border-top: 16px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

    }
    #progress li:after {
        content: '';
        border-left: 16px solid #E6E6E6;
        border-top: 16px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        z-index: 20;
    }

    #progress li.active {
        background: orange;
    }

    #progress li.active:after {
        border-left-color: orange;
    }

    #progress li.done {
        background: green;
    }

    #progress li.done:after {
        border-left-color: green;
    }
    </style>
```

Have an outputPanel and inside that an un-ordered list to show all your status with conditional styling. Basically just check the status of your current record and apply style `done` for the ones already past and `active` for the one which is currently the status.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="statusPanelId">
        <ul id="progress">
            <li class="{!IF(Change__c.Status__c == 'Created','active', 'done')}">Created</li>
            <li class="{!IF(Change__c.Status__c == 'Status2','active', IF(OR(Change__c.Status__c == 'Status3',Change__c.Status__c == 'Approved'), 'done', ''))}">Status2</li>
            <li class="{!IF(Change__c.Status__c == 'Status3','active', IF(Change__c.Status__c == 'Approved', 'done', ''))}">Status3</li>
            <li class="{!IF(Change__c.Status__c == 'Approved','active', '')}">Approved</li>
        </ul>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

This worked pretty well for me. You can of course redesign the CSS as per your need.

I have referred a blog from the internet which I am unable to find now. I will try to search it and put a reference. Credit should be given to the original author.